# Морфемный состав и производящая основа слова «предместье»

Tags: словообразование, морфология, морфемика, морфемный-разбор

Как известно, слово *предместье* — полонизм: польское *przedmieście* — суф.-преф. производное от *miasto* «город». Следовательно, по аналогии с другими заимствованиями в русском языке оно членится так: *предмест[j]-[э]*.

Тем не менее, в словаре А. И. Кузнецовой и Т. Ф. Ефремовой это слово включается в гнездо с корнем *мест* (видимо, на том основании, что исторически рус. *место* и польск. *miasto* однокоренные). Соответственно, морфемное членение таково: *пред-мест[j]-[э]*.

Если в первом случае очевидно, что в русском языке производящей основы нет, то во втором — возникает резонный вопрос: какова производящая основа? *Мест(j)*? Но ведь даже при диахроническом рассмотрении это представляется не вполне корректным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...В словаре А. И. Кузнецовой и Т. Ф. Ефремовой это слово включается в
>   гнездо с корнем *мест* (видимо, на том основании, что исторически рус.
>   *место* и польск. *miasto* однокоренные). Соответственно, морфемное
>   членение таково: *пред-мест[j]-[э].*
>
> Если в первом случае очевидно, что в русском языке производящей основы
>   нет, то во втором — возникает резонный вопрос: какова производящая
>   основа? *Мест(j)*?

У Тихонова — да, слово это непроизводное. Корень: ***предмест(j).***

Что же до Ефремовой… И такой вариант возможен.

*Предместье* ведь можно образовать и от слова *место* — так же, как образуются слова *пред-гор-j-е, пред-гроз-j-е, пред-плеч-j-е* и др. — приставочно-суффиксальным способом:

***мест***о -> **пред**-мест-**j**-е.

Answer (score 1):

1) Пред-мест-j-е. Это слово можно считать словообразовательной калькой.

"Словообразовательные кальки — это слова, полученные “поморфемным” переводом иностранного слова на русский язык. Калька обычно не ощущается как заимствованное слово, так как составлена из исконно русских морфем".

Например: предрассу́док – калька франц. préjugé .

2) Единого мнения по разбору таких слов нет, но вот ответ Грамоты.ру:

Вопрос № 280062
Здравствуйте! Есть ли приставка в слове развитие?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка
В слове развитие **выделяется приставка раз**-. Развитие – словообразовательная калька XVIII века немецкого Entwicklung: ent- – раз-, -wickl- – -ви-, -ung – -тие. Напомним, словообразовательная калька – это слово, созданное по иноязычной модели, но из материала данного языка.

Вообще говоря, членение на морфемы является более **прогрессивным подходом**, так как мы знаем значение каждой морфемы и считываем общий смысл слова с его морфемного состава. **А этимология слова менее значима для носителей языка по сравнению с его смыслом.**